# How to combine AudioQueuePause with AudioQueueGetCurrentTime to resume audio Playback in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, core-audio

My iPhone app plays a streaming audio from the internet.

I need to combine AudioQueuePause with AudioQueueGetCurrentTime to pause the audio stream and then resume the playback when the user presses the play again.

How do I implement AudioQueuePause with AudioQueueGetCurrentTime, for pausing and resuming the audio playback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't need to combine AudioQueuePause with AudioQueueGetCurrentTime to pause the audio stream, and then resume it afterwards when requested.

First I created two buttons (IBActions in my PlayerViewController.m), one for pause, and another for resuming the audio, besides the one I already had for start/stop. When starting it had to buffer first and then the audio would play. If I pressed the button again it would stop, getting rid of the current WiFi or 3G connection.

Then I just had to use **AudioQueuePause(inAudioQueue);** in a -(void)pauseAudioStreaming method and **AudioQueueStart(inAudioQueue, NULL)**; in a -(void)resume method. The NULL means that the audio will start ASAP, in the exact point where I paused it (then I concluded that there is no need to get the current time, using AudioQueueGetCurrentTime) like so:

```
- (void)pauseAudioStreaming
{
    AudioQueuePause(inAudioQueue);   
}

- (void)resume
{
    AudioQueueStart(inAudioQueue, NULL); 
}
```

Now it doesn't need to buffer again from the beginning of the audio, but it will pause and resume very fast when requested.